# How to use | operator in preg_match for searching between strings?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've seen many answers, but none seem to help me with my situation. I need to extract the comments from this text:

`Comments: These are the comments and they end at this full stop. Remember, you can only use the personal information...`

OR this text:

`Comments: These are the comments and they end at this full stop. You can only use the personal information...`

A working example is here: https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/1

But I can't seem to get this into PHP. I can get one to work with:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=Comments: )(.*?)(?= Remember, you can)/s";
```

But what is wrong with this?

```
$pattern = "/(?<=Comments: )(.*?)(?= Remember, you can)|(?<=Comments: )(.*?)(?= You can)/s";
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Actually they both [match](https://eval.in/697037) the context you're looking to capture. But I would recommend a different approach with your expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With preg_match_all you can get all result with your regex.

Try this:

```
/(?<=Comments: )(.*?)(?= Remember, you can)|(?<=Comments: )(.*?)(?= You can)/s
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/3)

Sample Code:

```
<?php

$re = '/(?<=Comments: )(.*?).(?= Remember, you can)|(?<=Comments: )(.*?)(?= You can)/sm';
$str = 'Comments: These are the comments and they end at this full stop. Remember, you can only use the personal information...

Comments: These are the comments and they end at this full stop. You can only use the personal information...';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

[Runt it here](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: Thanks - I needed preg_match_all

Comment: Actually, an afterthought - why does this pattern only work with preg_match_all???

Comment: @Warren You can see my answer too, with that regex pattern, it is working.

Comment: @Kumar, thanks but I don't thinks your answer answers my question with regard to needing multiple searches in one pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desire value also by preg_match like this. Here is code

```
<?php
$data="Comments: These are the comments and they end at this full stop. Remember, you can only use the personal information...";
preg_match("/(.*)(?<=Comments:)(.*?)(?= Remember, you can)(.*)/",$data,$m);
echo $m[2];
?>
```

**Output:**

These are the comments and they end at this full stop.

Or you can use

print_r($m) it will print all the value you capture with regex. 
Hope it helps you.